# Black bar shown when UITabBar is hidden on iPhone

Tags: ios, uiwebview, storyboard, uitabbar

I'm purposefully hiding my tab-bar upon viewing a controller consisting of a `UIWebView`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

    self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
}
```

In my storyboard, for this controller, I've set the bottom bar to be "None":

[image]

My storyboard shows that the web-view is now taking up all available space at the bottom:

[image]

However, I know have a black bar where my tab bar used to be:

[image]

Does anyone know why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` in `viewWillAppear` doesn't do anything.

Set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` before you push to this view controller.

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
//hide tabbar
myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
//add it to stack.
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

Or in storyboard like this

[image]